# Removing file locks in Windows and Java

Tags: java, windows, file-locking

I have a Java program that opens a file using the RandomAccessFile class.

I'd like to be able to rename that file while it is opened by Java. In Unix, this isn't a problem. Does anyone know how I can do this in Windows?

Should I set Java to open it a certain way?

Thanks in advance.

Edit, clarification: I'd like to be able to set this file sharing access in my Java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close any handles on the file at any way. E.g. a `FileOutputStream` on that `File` must be closed before you can rename it. That's just the way how the Windows file system works.

Comment: BalusC, there is no way I can change the name while the handle is open? Tat is how Unix does it, right?

Answer (score -2):

```
in_stream.close();            
out_stream.getChannel().close();
out_stream.close();
```

Anyhow in Windows it stay locked :*(